# Track progress when using TPL's Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library, plinq

What is the best way way to track progress in the following

```
long total = Products.LongCount();
long current = 0;
double Progress = 0.0;

Parallel.ForEach(Products, product =>
{
    try
    {
        var price = GetPrice(SystemAccount, product);
        SavePrice(product,price);
    }
    finally
    {
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref this.current);
    }});
```

I want to update the progress variable from 0.0 to 1.0 (current/total) but i don't want to use anything that would have an adverse effect on the parallelism.

Comment: What is the progress being used for? Updating a UI? If so, could you get the UI to update itself (with a timer) based on the value of current and total? Doing too many updates per second on a UI can block it. Better to have the UI set the pace of updates rather than the processor.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Jon's solution is good, if you need simple synchronization like this, your first attempt should almost always use `lock`. But if you measure that the locking slows things too much, you should think about using something like `Interlocked`.

In this case, I would use `Interlocked.Increment` to increment the current count, and change `Progress` into a property:

```
private long total;
private long current;
public double Progress
{
    get
    {
        if (total == 0)
            return 0;
        return (double)current / total;
    }
}

…

this.total = Products.LongCount();
this.current = 0;

Parallel.ForEach(Products, product =>
{
    try
    {
        var price = GetPrice(SystemAccount, product);
        SavePrice(product, price);
    }
    finally
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref this.current);
    }
});
```

Also, you might want to consider what to do with exceptions, I'm not sure that iterations that ended with an exception should be counted as done.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are just doing a few quick calculations, ensure atomicity by locking on an appropriate object:

```
long total = Products.LongCount();
long current = 0;
double Progress = 0.0;
var lockTarget = new object();

Parallel.ForEach(Products, product =>
{
    try
    {
        var price = GetPrice(SystemAccount, product);
        SavePrice(product,price);
    }
    finally
    {
        lock (lockTarget) {
            Progress = ++this.current / total;
        }
    }});
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution without using any blocking in the body:

```
long total = Products.LongCount();
BlockingCollection<MyState> states = new BlockingCollection<MyState>();

Parallel.ForEach(Products, () =>
{
    MyState myState = new MyState();
    states.Add(myState);
    return myState;
},
(i, state, arg3, myState) =>
{
    try
    {
        var price = GetPrice(SystemAccount, product);
        SavePrice(product,price);
    }
    finally
    {
        myState.value++;
        return myState;
    }
},
i => { }
);
```

Then, to access the current progress:

```
(float)states.Sum(state => state.value) / total
```

Comment: This seems like way too complicated for something as simple as this.